# We want a nice list of events pulling from Eventbrite

Tags: eventbrite

I'm new to Eventbrite. I would like to list out events from Eventbrite using the event_search() method. I am using the following url and the user api key (https://www.eventbrite.com/userkeyapi):
https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_search?app_key=userapikey&keywords=&city=&dat.

But I got an error message like

`<error><error_message>This application key is not valid.</error_message>  <error_type>Application Key Error</error_type></error>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your events list from Eventbrite using the "organizer_list_events" method.

https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/organizer_list_events?app_key={your applicaton key}&id={your id}. I got My Events list successfully with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You need an [API key](https://www.eventbrite.com/api/key), not a [user key](https://www.eventbrite.com/userkeyapi/) - see http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

You can get your events list from Eventbrite using the "organizer_list_events" method.

https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/organizer_list_events?app_key={your applicaton key}&id={your id}. I got My Events list successfully with this method.
 This code is not working